# Openshift gear CPU usage

Tags: cpu, openshift, metrics, quota

I use collectd to get metrics of the app. *oo-cgroup-read* allows to get memory and disc metrics, but I don't see how to get CPU metrics.

collectd seems pulls system info from */proc* (or smth like that) and this not really correct in OpenShift environment.

Is it possible to get CPU usage and quota for a gear?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ oo-cgroup-read cpuacct.usage
242233947808

$ echo "cpu: $((`oo-cgroup-read cpuacct.usage` / 1000000000)) sec"
cpu: 242 sec
```

Comment: Don't think it's a correct metric for CPU usage. It just shows total time consumed by tasks. And I need usage in % of quota.

Comment: How about Memory usage?